# Child escort rules/regulations from US to Europe

Tags: europe, children, minors, us-residents

We would like to invite our niece from the US. She is 12 years old. She lives with her mother (our sister) but she is the child from the first marriage.

She has a green card in the US and we arranged her visa for Schengen zone.

Do airlines give escort service for children without parents? What kind of documents should we prepare?

Comment: Search your airline's site for "unaccompanied minors".

Comment: And here's a good [US Department of Transportation](http://airconsumer.ost.dot.gov/publications/kidsalone.pdf) guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules differ from airline to airline, however most airlines will have rules about unaccompanied minors, and these rules are always available on the airlines' websites.  Note that some airlines may charge an extra fee for this service.

As your niece has a green card, I assume she either have a passport from another country, a US re-entry permit or a refugee traveller's document. I assume that the visa is stamped into that document.

Apart from the passport/visa, as the child will be travelling outside the country, some airlines require a notarised letter from the child's parents indicating their agreement for the child to travel without them (called *parental consent letter*).  Some airlines will even require both parents (or guardians) to sign such letters.

Finally, note that often airlines will not sell tickets for unaccompanied minors via their websites - and you are required to either by the ticket on the phone or at the airline's office.

There are no other requirements other that these.  I had my nephew from abroad visit me in the UK - and had no issues whatsoever. I do recommend talking to an airline directly if you have any concerns.

Answer (score 3):

Just about every airline has an unaccompanied minor service, some make it mandatory for certain age brackets. Here's a few, from [Delta](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/support/faqs/preparing-for-your-trip/children-traveling-alone-faqs.html), [KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/us_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/children/umnr_yp_framed.htm) and [United](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/specialneeds/minors/default.aspx) for example. They'll each have their own conditions (which you can find on their websites), some require an adult to drop them off and check-in, to sign an authorization form or to provide contact information.

Your niece needs her own passport to travel to Europe (I'm assuming she already has a visa if that's required), she can't be on her parents' passport. Obviously she also needs her green card to get back to the US after.

Comment: @EugenMartynov you're welcome. It helps to mark as accepted whichever answer you found most useful

Comment: Both answers are giving hope and understanding what to do. If I could I would accept both

Comment: @EugenMartynov please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers you can select one. Neither person's feelings will be hurt, they are grown ups and established users on the site.