# Can my 15 year old son travel back alone to home country (India) from the UK?

Tags: air-travel, uk, indian-citizens, children

My son got a child visit visa for the UK; he accompanied me while entering the UK. Now, can he travel back to our home country (India) without being accompanied?

Comment: Virtually every airline has an [unaccompanied minor](https://www.google.com/search?q=unaccompanied+minors&oq=unaccomp&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4343j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) option for travel. Typically you might pay a little extra. Just call the airline for specifics for your particular airline. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81112/child-escort-rules-regulations-from-us-to-europe/81114#81114

Comment: Does his visa require that he be accompanied? If it does, several answers here (which I can't find at the moment) have stated that this _includes_ that he must be accompanied on the flight out of the UK.

Comment: If the son has an accompanied child visa this is a duplicate of [Can a child enter the UK on an accompanied visa and then leave the country alone?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61387/19560)

Comment: Notwithstanding the policy of the airline, a lot depends on whether you want to sponsor your son (or anyone else) again. You will forfeit that opportunity if UKVI finds out you were in breach.